# Can not get a user's phone number with KeyboardButton

Tags: python, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I have a simple telegram bot with a KeyboardButton that appears when a user presses on "Start". After the user presses on KeyboardButton a window appears and in that window the user presses a button "Share phone number". I need to get this phone number but a "Contact" object in response is empty. The module that I use - pyTelegramBotApi.

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def register(message):
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(one_time_keyboard=True)
    reg_button = types.KeyboardButton(text="Share your phone number", request_contact=True)
    keyboard.add(reg_button)
    response = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 
                                "You should share your phone number", 
                                reply_markup=keyboard)
    print(response.contact)  # response.contact = None here

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Is that a right way to get a phone number from user? If no, how can i get it?

Answer (score 3):

You should define new handler for contact

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def contact_handler(message):
    print(message.contact.phone_number)
```

Answer (score 2):

No it's wrong. You should define a new `handler` to handle the `contact`.

```
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.contact, get_contact))
```

then you should define your `get_contact` function:

```
def get_contact(bot, update):
   chat_id = update.message.chat_id
   phone_number = update.message.contact.phone_number
   other stuffs...
```

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I added the wrong module in tags. I'm using pyTelegramBotAPI, not python-telegram-bot.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_contact(message):
    print(message.contact.phone_number)
```

You should use handler with filter.
It is not text it is contact.